# Regex remove word from a specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I have tried to remove a the "Admin" word in this string

```
1H|\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||Admin||||P|1|20150511083525
1D
```

with this regex

```
[^\w\b(Admin\])\b.-]+
```

and the output is `1H|ARCHITECT|8.10|F3453010030|H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|Admin|P|1|20150511083525|1D`

it does not remove the Admin word.

output desired:

`1H|ARCHITECT|8.10|F3453010030|H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|P|1|20150511083525|1D`

i need help to improve the regex :(

Comment: Have you tried String.Replace ?

Comment: no i have not tried, but the program i wrote is based on that regex and the data is dynamically changing the admin word can change to different index.

Comment: Kevin, so what?  string.Replace would still work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your regex should be like this

```
string input = @"1H|\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||Admin||||P|1|20150511083525
    1D";
string pattern = @"([^\w]*Admin[^\w]*)+|[|\\^&\r\n]+";
string replacement = "|";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: hello, what if i have two admins 1H|\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||Admin|Admin|||P|1|20150511083525

Comment: hello there is just one problem if the characters have space it should replace space with |

Comment: use this `([^\w]*Admin[^\w]*)+|[|\\^&\r\n\s]+`

Answer (score 4):

Not necessary to use regex here. You can use [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) function;

```
yourString.Replace("Admin|", string.Empty);
```

If using Regex is important for you - try this variant:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\bAdmin|\b");
var output = r.Replace(s, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Or even `yourString.Replace("|Admin|", "||");` if "Admin" were to occur in other places.

Comment: Won't remove "empty spaces" - `||` - which is expected if you see the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 2 step solution: use your regex (with `|` added to the negated character class) and `\bAdmin\b` as an alternative (in your regex, it was not treated as a sequence of characters, but individual character `a`, `d`..., `\b` inside a character class matches a backspace symbol, not a word boundary) to  replace with `|` and then join the string back:

```
var str = "1H|\\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||Admin||||P|1|20150511083525\r\n1D";
var res = string.Join("|", Regex.Replace(str, @"[^|\w.-]+|\bAdmin\b", "|").Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Result: [image]

**Update**

You can also replace that all with one pass using the following regex:

```
\W*Admin\W*|[\\|^&\s]+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CW*Admin%5CW*%7C%5B%7C%5C%5C%5E%26%5Cs%5D%2B&i=1H%7C%5C%5E%26%7C%7C%7CARCHITECT%5E8.10%5EF3453010030%5EH1P1O1R1C1Q1L1%7C%7C%7CAdmin%7C%7C%7C%7CP%7C1%7C20150511083525%0D%0A%20%20%20%201D&r=%7C)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

100% working

```
 Regex.Replace(@"1H|\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||Admin||||P|1|20150511083525  1D", "Admin", "",System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

changes :

1: @ before string and

2:System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Comment: As (kind of) said in another comment, change the regex (second argument - `Admin`) to `\|Admin\|' to remove the vertical bar as well. Then add `|\||` to remove "empty spaces" and exchange with `|`. I.e. `"\|Admin\||\||"` as regex (2nd argument) and `"|"` as replacement string (3rd argument). It's not perfect because if `Admin`, or an empty space, is in the begining or end of the string, it won't work. It's possible to fix, but if it isn't necessary, I don't want to complicate it further ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply via

```
\|*Admin\|*
```

You can remove using this regex and replace by `|`.
See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/81